# Find nested Control inside a user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, controls

Hi I have a **panel** that contains a **usercontrol** that contains a **repeater** that can have one or more **checkboxes**.

I want to get status of all check boxes that currently are in the panel.

My current code is

```
bool isChecked = false;

        foreach (Control control in pnlLoanProcess.Controls)
        {
            if (control is BookLoanActions)
            {
                BookLoanActions uc = (BookLoanActions)control;

                foreach (Control c in uc.Controls)
                {

                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Repeater))
                    {
                        Repeater rptr = (Repeater)c;
                        foreach (Control c1 in rptr.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c1.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                            {
                                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)c1;
                                if (chkBox.Checked)
                                    isChecked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a shorter/better way to do this?

Comment: Set `tag` value for each control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there is...

```
foreach (var bla in pnlLoanProcess.Controls.OfType<BookLoanActions>())
{
    foreach (var rptr in bla.Controls.OfType<Repeater>())
    {
        isChecked = rtpr.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(c => c.IsChecked));
    }
}
```

You could probably even shorten that up with some clever LINQ.